# MIN_TREEIFY_CAPACITY in HashMap

Tags: java-8, hashmap

The documentation says below

```
    /**
     * The smallest table capacity for which bins may be treeified.
     * (Otherwise the table is resized if too many nodes in a bin.)
     * Should be at least 4 * TREEIFY_THRESHOLD to avoid conflicts
     * between resizing and treeification thresholds.
     */
```

Could you explain the rationale or logic behind having this parameter as atleast 4 * TREEIFY_THRESHOLD

Comment: Perhaps a value determined by benchmarking typical (or worst case) datasets. From looking at the algorithm, I can’t derive that factor…

Answer (score 0):

MIN_TREEIFY_CAPACITY means that the total buckets in the hashmap should be 64 so that a bucket can be transformed from Linked list to Red Black tree (self balancing BST).
Also TREEIFY_THRESHOLD condition too should be met. i.e each bucket should have 8 or more entries.

Answer (score 0):

This constant basically says not to start making buckets into trees if our hash map is very small — it should resize to be larger first instead.

Comment: Yes ... but the question is asking why was that particular constant chosen; e.g. why 4 rather than (say) 2 or 8?  And Holger's comment from 5 years ago is probably the best answer we can provide.

Answer (score -1):

As of java 8, when the Entries in a linked list reaches 8 (MIN_TREEIFY_CAPACITY;), it converts the linked list to a Balanced Tree . This improved the performance a million times.